# Message actuator/sensor across scenes?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, scene

In the BGE, I'm trying to send a message from one scene to an overlay scene. The subject in the main scene's actuator matches the overlay scene's sensor. I've also made sure I'm sending the message to the right object (but also tried leaving it blank - sending to all objects - no luck).

The overlay scene doesn't seem to receive the the message at all. I genuinely do not have a clue of what's going on. I thought you could send messages between scenes. The overlay scene is inactive when sending this message btw. It's going to be an inventory screen that's only visible when player presses <kbd>I</kbd> (overlay scene).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scene has to be active in order for objects within it to receive and process messages.

Instead of removing the overlay scene to hide the inventory, you should just move/rotate the camera to look away at some empty space.